# Errors importing SQL dump containing functions used in indexes

Tags: postgresql, function, indexing, pg-dump, postgresql-11

On PostgreSQL 11, I'm regularly dumping backup snapshots and sometimes import them on a development system with the same setup. Nothing fancy there:

```
# Dump
ps_dump -OU <user> <database> >dump.sql
# Restore
psql -U <user> -f dump.sql <database>
```

However, two indexes in the dump are throwing errors when restoring. I've boiled it down to the following dump with everything unrelated stripped:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 11.2
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.2

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Name: add_days(timestamp without time zone, integer, text); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE FUNCTION public.add_days(timestamp without time zone, integer, text DEFAULT 'Europe/Zurich'::text) RETURNS timestamp without time zone
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
    SET search_path TO 'public', 'pg_temp'
    AS $_$
          SELECT (($1::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE $3 + INTERVAL '1 day' * $2) AT TIME ZONE $3)::timestamp
        $_$;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: projects; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.projects (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    started_at timestamp without time zone,
    duration integer
);

--
-- Name: ended_at(public.projects); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE FUNCTION public.ended_at(public.projects) RETURNS timestamp without time zone
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE
    AS $_$
          SELECT add_days($1.started_at, $1.duration)
        $_$;

--
-- Name: index_projects_on_ended_at; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE INDEX index_projects_on_ended_at ON public.projects USING btree (public.ended_at(projects.*));
```

Restoring this dump produces the following error:

```
psql:dumped.sql:60: ERROR:  function add_days(timestamp without time zone, integer) does not exist
LINE 2:           SELECT add_days($1.started_at, $1.duration)
                     ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:
      SELECT add_days($1.started_at, $1.duration)

CONTEXT:  SQL function "ended_at" during inlining
```

The following fixes the problem: Prefix `add_days` with the schema to read as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.ended_at(public.projects) RETURNS timestamp without time zone
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE
    AS $_$
          SELECT public.add_days($1.started_at, $1.duration)
        $_$;
```

Case closed? Not quite. I'd like to understand what the problem is here.

I guess, the line `SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);` generated by pg_dump prevents `add_days` from being found unless with an explicit schema prefixed.

However, why does the following alternative (adding the search_path) not work?

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.ended_at(public.projects) RETURNS timestamp without time zone
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE
    SET search_path TO 'public', 'pg_temp'
    AS $_$
          SELECT add_days($1.started_at, $1.duration)
        $_$;
```

This triggers an entirely different error:

```
psql:dumped.sql:58: ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

Okay, now I'm confused. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different questions here.

1. **Why do you get the error when you restore the dump?**

   The problem is caused by [this](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=3d2aed664ee8271fd6c721ed0aa10168cda112ea) patch that fixed a security problem of PostgreSQL.

   Before that change, `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` would set the `search_path` to something like this:

   ```
   SET search_path = dumped_schema, pg_catalog;
   ```

   The problem with that is that any function or operator used in index definitions (and elsewhere) would be searched in `dumped_schema` first.

   A malicious user could use that to get his functions executed with superuser privileges during a restore.

   You have already figured out how to solve the problem.

   This is admittedly annoying, but given that up to now your function was at the mercy of the current `search_path` setting (which anybody can change with a simple `SET` command), I would see it as an improvement in its own right.
2. **Why does it not work to `SET search_path` on the function?**

   The problem here is that any function that is used in an index must be `IMMUTABLE` (must return the same results for the same arguments no matter what), else the index could become corrupted. However, `ended_at` is `STABLE` and not `IMMUTABLE`.

   The problem is “masked” in your original setup, because PostgreSQL could *inline* the function, that is, replace the function call with its definition. Now `add_days` *is* marked `IMMUTABLE`, so that is fine.

   After setting the `search_path` on the function, the function can no longer be inlined, so now you get the error message.

   I'd say you should declare `ended_at` as `IMMUTABLE` too.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Pg12 brings [generated columns](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/16/1443/), this will do away with the STABLE vs. IMMUTABLE problem in this context I guess.